# how to add the timestamp of each parallel process appending a dictionary in the list?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have code like this:

```
import requests
import multiprocessing as mp
import json
import time

BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/employees'

with open('data2.json', 'r') as f:
    list_dict = json.load(f)

def resource_post(post_data):
    stuff_got = []
    response = requests.post(BASE_URL, json=post_data)
    stuff_got.append(response.json())
    print(stuff_got)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return stuff_got

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    start=time.time()
    with mp.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        pool.imap(resource_post, list_dict)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    elapsed = (time.time() - start)  
    print("\n","time elapsed is :", elapsed)
```

on file data2.json there are several dictionaries in the list without timestamp, example:

```
[{"TransID":123123,"User":"User1","ServiceID":62801238,"ProjID":"1-Proj"},{"TransID":123124,"User":"User1","ServiceID":62801238,"ProjID":"1-Proj"}]
```

on BASE_URL there is data like this:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "TransID": "123122",
      "User": "user1",
      "timestamp": "20200224 12:33:33:334",
      "ServiceID": "62801238",
      "ProjID": "1-Proj"
    }
  ]
}
```

expected output after parallel processes and add the timestamp based on each processed:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "TransID": 123122,
      "User": "user1",
      "timestamp": "20200224 12:33:33:334",
      "ServiceID": "62801238",
      "ProjID": "1-Proj"
    },
    {
      "TransID": 123123,
      "User": "User1",
      "timestamp": "20200310 9:20:33:334"
      "ServiceID": 62801238,
      "ProjID": "1-Proj",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "TransID": 123124,
      "User": "User1",
      "timestamp": "20200310 9:20:35:330"
      "ServiceID": 62801238,
      "ProjID": "1-Proj",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: The timestamp will be added in each dictionary according to the time each dictionary is processed and entered into the list.

so what should I add in my code so that the output of each process has an additional timestamp.
please help me. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can append timestamp key and value in `post_data` dict

```
def resource_post(post_data):
    stuff_got = []
    post_data["timestamp"] = time.time()  # Add the timestamp in the required format here
    response = requests.post(BASE_URL, json=post_data)
    stuff_got.append(response.json())
    print(stuff_got)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    return stuff_got
```

Comment: hallo guys, I have tried your way but the timestamp only appears in the log when running the process, it is not sent to db.json, is there something wrong or should I add something?

Comment: Updated the code snippet above, please try.

Comment: thank you sir, the problem has been resolved :)

Comment: @Irfan If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept the answer so that the author of the answer gets due credit